# Send x-api-key with POST request header Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-3.8, request-headers

I was given a problem that stated:

```
#Write a script that uses a web API to create a social media post.
#There is a tweet bot API listening at http://127.0.0.1:8082, GET / returns basic info about the API.
#POST / with x-api-key:tweetbotkeyv1 and data with user tweetbotuser and a status-update of alientest.
```

My code responds that I did not provide the x-api-key, but it is in the header.  My code:

```html
#
# Tweet bot API listening at http://127.0.0.1:8082.
# GET / returns basic info about api. POST / with x-api-key:tweetbotkeyv1
# and data with user tweetbotuser and status-update of alientest
#

import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

data = urllib.parse.urlencode({ 
  
  "x-api-key": "tweetbotkeyv1",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "User-agent": "tweetbotuser",
  "status-update": "alientest"
})


url = "http://127.0.0.1:8082"

data = data.encode("ascii")
with urllib.request.urlopen(url, data) as f:
    print(f.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

returns:

```
{"success": "false", "message":"x-api-key Not provided", "flag":""}
```

Is there something wrong with the header?

Comment: The `data` dictionary should be sent as request `headers`, not `data`.  As `urllib.request.urlopen` doesn't directly support headers, use a `Request` object instead, or (even better) use python `requests` (not part of the base python library, must be installed via pip or equivalent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The url, parameters and header must be submitted in strict order:
`urllib.request.Request(url, post_param, header)`
the result will be: `{"success": "true", "message":"Well done", "flag":"<the flag will be show here>"}`

Here is the working solution

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8082/"
header={"x-api-key" : 'tweetbotkeyv1'}
post_param = urllib.parse.urlencode({
                    'user' : 'tweetbotuser',
           'status-update' : 'alientest'
          }).encode('UTF-8')

req = urllib.request.Request(url, post_param, header)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

print(response.read())
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ollie No worries

Comment: hi, i have no "user" and "status-uptade" information. what should I do